# Are there any more movies announced after Fantastic Beasts?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, sequels, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

I just saw *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them* and was not expecting to see

> Johnny Depp playing Gellert Grindelwald.

I would be surprised that such a prominent actor would have a few minutes on screen as such an important character in the HP universe. Have there been any official announced/plans to pursue movies that feature this character more prominently?

Comment: Forgive me if this is off-topic. I looked at the [on-topic page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and did see that "rumors about a specific title or series" are off-topic, but I am looking only for official announcements and interviews from those who would have a say in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, four more sequels are planned to be exact.

From [variety.com](http://variety.com/2016/film/news/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-five-movies-1201888226/)

> “We always knew that it was going to be more than one movie — we knew that from the start — so we set a trilogy as a sort of placeholder, because we knew there would be more than one movie, “Rowling said at the Empire Theatre in London.” But I’ve now done the plotting properly, so we’re pretty sure it’s going to be five movies.”

And from [collider.com](http://collider.com/fantastic-beasts-2-johnny-depp-grindelwald/):

> > “We do go back to the U.K. in the second film as well–it’s U.K. and Paris. I’m not sure where Jo is setting the rest of the movies, but they’ll be European-centric. I think it will be difficult to ignore America, but the next one is predominately Europe.”
>
> And finally, Yates teased that Ezra Miller’s character Credence plays a pivotal role in the follow-up:
>
> > “Credence, we follow Credence further. He becomes quite pivotal actually, Credence is quite crucial.”

Even it's said that Johnny Depp will be having major role in follow-up film.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that Credence plays a prominent role considering how they left his story. I guess that will be part of the surprise for the next movie!

Comment: @DavidK Not that big of surprise as we do see part of obscure did survived when Newt noticed

Comment: (Possible spoiler alert) I thought what they did to poor, abused, distressed Credence was tragic, unforgivable.  Bringing him back will be the only way to redeem this series for me.

Answer (score 8):

### There will be five total movies.

[image]

> - https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/800647497848934400

As a five movie saga, the assumption is that the set will lead up to and end with the battle between Grindlewald and Dumbledore.

Comment: Just to get a clarification. I have not yet seen nor read the book, but does this movie cover roughly 1/5 of the book then and other four are sequels? Or this movie covers full story and upcoming movies will be of other Rowling materials or just an expansion of a story line.

Comment: @paharet the original book is a small companion to Harry Potter. It contains no story and is basically a monster manual. I believe they will have movie novelizations of the five films.